# NameError: name 'stock' is not defined

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I've been trying to recreate https://weikaiwei.com/python/stocker/ python stock analysis.
Everything is smooth sailing until I got into the fifth step

> V. Prophet model

```
model, model_data = stock.create_prophet_model(days=10)
```

According to the website, there should be historical and predicted stock prices.
But, all i got is :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-be019f9334b5> in
  <module>
    ----> 1 model, model_data = stock.create_prophet_model(days=10) NameError: name 'stock' is not defined
```

I wonder where did I go wrong with the prophet model. Can anyone please kindly give me an insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used this import function and this variable in your code

```
from stocker import Stocker
stock = Stocker(stockNo, df)
```

Comment: yes I did. But. the next step just doesn't work. It is driving me nuts.